# Parser Issue with BeautifulSoup

Tags: json, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a script that loops through multiple pages and it is working fine until it gets to page 19.  I get the error message:

```
if container.find(text="License: ").nextSibling.img:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nextSibling'
```

That element exists on page 19. I have also included an else statement for when it doesn't.  I have tried `requests` instead of `urlopen` to see if that makes a difference and have even changed the parser from `html.parser` to `html5lib` to `lxml` with no luck. I think it might be a parser issue but I am not sure what the solution might be.  Here is my script:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import json

base_url = "https://www.doabooks.org/"

data = []
n = 85
for i in range(1, n+1):
    if (i == 1):
    # handle first page
       response = urlopen(base_url)
    response = urlopen(base_url + "doab?func=browse&page=" + str(i) + "&queryField=A&uiLanguage=en")
    page_html = response.read()
    response.close()

    #html parsing
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html5lib")

    #grabs info for each book
    containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"data"})

    for container in containers:
       item = {}
       item['type'] = "Open Access Book"
       item['title'] = container.span.text.strip()
       item['author'] =container.a.text
       item['link'] = "https://www.doabooks.org" + container.find('a', {'itemprop' : 'url'})['href']
       item['source'] = "Directory of Open Access Books"
       if container.div.find('a', {'itemprop' : 'about'}):
          item['subject'] = container.div.find('a', {'itemprop' : 'about'}).text.lstrip()
       else: 
          item['subject'] = ''
       item['base_url'] = "https://www.doabooks.org/"
       if container.find(text="License: ").nextSibling.img:
           item['license'] = container.find(text="License: ").nextSibling['href']
       else:
           item['license'] = container.find(text="License: ").nextSibling.text

       item['license_url'] = container.find(text="License: ").nextSibling['href']
       data.append(item) # add the item to the list

   with open("./json/doab-a.json", "w") as writeJSON:
      json.dump(data, writeJSON, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book with the title "After Conversion" on https://www.doabooks.org/doab?func=browse&page=19&queryField=A&uiLanguage=en has no "License" given, so in your code

```
container.find(text="License: ")
```

is None so you can't get

```
.nextSibling.img
```

from the NoneType object so it throws an exception. Try something like this:

```
if not container.find(string="License: "):
    item['license_url'] = item['license'] = "Not Specified"
else:
    if container.find(string="License: ").nextSibling.img:
        item['license'] = container.find(string="License: ").nextSibling['href']
    else:
        item['license'] = container.find(string="License: ").nextSibling.text
    item['license_url'] = container.find(string="License: ").nextSibling['href']
```